# ISingleResult Cast in Code?

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, ienumerable, datacontext

I have a sproc in my Linq to SQL (.NET 4.0) designer that returns the default ISingleResult. I wanted it to return something of Type "MyTable", so I made the change in the designer.
So this works:

```
List<MyTable> return = dataContext.MySproc.ToList();
```

However, I would rather cast/convert the return from the sproc in code to stay away from the designer. For some reason I can't get the trick of converting ISingleResult from the sproc into List. Can someone help me with the syntax?

Note, if this is easier in EF and someone can point me to HOWTOs using that toolset, I'm all ears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your ISingleResult into the constructor of List.